# eig(a,b) in Python giving error "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

According to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html, the equivalent numpy expression for the MATLAB `[V,D]=eig(a,b)` is `V,D = np.linalg.eig(a,b)`.

But when I try this I get the error:

```
TypeError: eig() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I'm confused, the documentation says `np.linalg.eig` can take two arguments?

Curiously, when I look at the `linalg` documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/routines.linalg.html, under the heading 'Matrix eigenvalues' there is no mention of `linalg.eig` taking two arguments?

How can I get `eig` to take two arguments like in MATLAB?

### This works in MATLAB

```
a = diag(ones(3,1));
b = diag(2*ones(3,1));
[V,D] = eig(a,b)
```

Output:

```
V =

    0.7071         0         0
         0    0.7071         0
         0         0    0.7071


D =

    0.5000         0         0
         0    0.5000         0
         0         0    0.5000
```

### This doesn't work in Python

```
import numpy as np

a = np.diag(np.ones(3))
b = np.diag(2*np.ones(3))

V,D = np.linalg.eig(a,b)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: eig() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: I've opened a pull request to fix this in the documentation, hopefully it will be fixed in the next version.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, as of 1.16 it is still in the documentation. I opened a new issue #13596 at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13596

Comment: Just to make full circle, @AustinDowney, when I said "next version" I meant "next version as of this writing". When this question was asked numpy 1.16 was brand new, and docs are rarely rebuilt (there is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html but no https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.2/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html). I expect the change to be there starting with 1.17. This change was probably not deemed critical enough to merit introducing sooner (which I can agree with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saw in the docs of [`numpy.linalg.eig`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html#numpy.linalg.eig), it only accepts a single array argument and correspondingly it doesn't compute generalized eigenvalue problems.

Fortunately we have [`scipy.linalg.eig`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html):

```
scipy.linalg.eig(a, b=None, left=False, right=True, overwrite_a=False, overwrite_b=False, check_finite=True, homogeneous_eigvals=False)

    Solve an ordinary or generalized eigenvalue problem of a square matrix.
```

Here's your example case:

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy.linalg 

a = np.diag(np.ones(3)) 
b = np.diag(2*np.ones(3)) 
eigvals,eigvects = scipy.linalg.eig(a, b)
```

Now we have

```
>>> eigvals
array([0.5+0.j, 0.5+0.j, 0.5+0.j])

>>> eigvects
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

The difference in the eigenvectors might be due to a different choice in normalization for the eigenvalues. I'd check with two nontrivial matrices and see if the results correspond to one another (comparing corresponding eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs, of course).